# Windows form hidden web browser control does not bring the IE window to foreground

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, outlook-addin

I have created add in for Outlook 2013. It has got a hidden web browser control within it. On button click Web browser loads the speciified data in Internet Explorer window. Content is loading but the IE window does not come to foreground and my outlook will continue be in focus. IE keeps blinking at the task bar.

I want the IE window be in foreground.

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: Do you want IE to launch inside Outlook window or outside Outlook in the browser window ?

Comment: hi sanjay, Want to launch IE outside the outlook window.

Comment: webBrowserReporting.Navigate(serviceUrl, "_blank", xmlBytes,
                  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n");

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a Windows Form on top of Outlook window you need to specify the parent window handle. In your case it will be the explorer window handle. To get the handle you need to cast an instance of the Explorer class to the [IOleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102(v=vs.85).aspx) interface which provides the [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.

The Show or ShowDialog methods of the System.Windows.Form class accepts an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inteface which represents the handle of the parent window. Thus, your window will be shown on top of the parent one.

Comment: Hi Eugene , Thanks for your help. It used to work fine but suddenly i got this problem. Now it happens everytime. Can you suggest anything other than using IOleWindow.

Comment: problem is in a debug mode . It works fine. internet Explorerlaunched by hidden web browser control opens in foreground. But when i install the addin in system.then on button click the internet Explorer Windows opens in the background and outlook stays on the top. but i want the ie window in front.

Comment: Try to minimize the Outlook window. See the [WindowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866771(v=office.15).aspx) property for more information.

Comment: I have implemented this . But I want the outlook to be on top, when user closes the Internet explorer but now i get minimized outlook.
I am reading in so many forums where the issue is hidden web browser stealing focus . But in my case its not giving focus to IE which is opened by hidden web browser . Am i doing any mistake here ? or it is giving focus to hidden control which is in the add in of outlook thats why the IE is not coming  in front.
and also documentComplete event is also not firing.

I am damn confused... :( :(

Answer (score 0):

"Want to launch IE outside the outlook window. – "

In that case use - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(v=vs.110).aspx

Process.Start("http://URL");

This will launch the default browser and navigate to the URL specified.

Comment: But along with opening browser.i need to do a HTTP post. So i am using web browser control.